# Return nested List from web api using Entity Framework and navigation properties

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ado.net

I'm trying to return a JSON with a nested list using Navigation properties but I keep getting null in the 'Usuario' collection here's the output.

```
 [
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "id": 1,
    "encabezado": "Como llamar a un metodo en c#",
    "cuerpo": "Estoy intentando llamar un metodo metodo() pero no puedo alguna sugerencia xD?",
    "points": 0,
    "Usuario": null,
    "Respuestas": []
  },
  {
    "$id": "2",
    "id": 2,
    "encabezado": "Como cambiar conection String",
    "cuerpo": "Es posible cambiar el conection string en asp.net si ya esta creada?",
    "points": 1,
    "Usuario": null,
    "Respuestas": []
  }
]
```

here's my .edmx

[image]

And finally this is where I have the web api

```
namespace AskTecProject.Controllers
{
    public class QuestionController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public List<Pregunta> GetQuestions()
        {
            using (asktecdbEntities entities = new asktecdbEntities())
            {
                List<Pregunta> p = entities.Usuarios.Where(m => m.id.Equals(1)).SelectMany(m => m.Preguntas).ToList<Pregunta>();
                return p;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got his query from [Getting a related collection](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4) but I'm still having trouble with this, I'll appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Eager Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

```
List<Pregunta> preguntas = entities.Usuarios
       .Where(u => u.id.Equals(1))
       .SelectMany(u => u.Preguntas)
       .Include(p => p.Usuario) // here
       .ToList<Pregunta>();
```

Side note - seems like all your Preguntas entities will have same Usuario entity with id = 1. Also you don't need to specify generic parameter for `ToList` method - parameter should be inferred.

Comment: Thank you Sergey, I was having trouble for a second, cause I didn't had Systems.Data.Entity imported and I was getting the Include method from other library. But It works great, thanks again.